# Orbital Elements Mars near June 2014

Tags: orbital-elements

do you know any website in which I could obtain orbital elements of planets at some date?

For instance, I'm now needing the orbital elements of Mars around June, 2014.

Thanks!

Comment: http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @barrycarter mentioned you can use the Horizons web interface from JPL: http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi

You can change the setting in the web form by clicking on the [change] links for the different settings (for instance the time span or the planet). There are several different settings that can be changed to get different outputs (table columns) and such.

If you really want the orbital elements (and not just the Right Ascension and Declination) you will have to select ELEMENTS in the Ephemeris type settings.

You then get a table with the following elements:

- JDCT     Epoch Julian Date, Coordinate Time
- EC     Eccentricity, e
- QR     Periapsis distance, q (AU)
- IN     Inclination w.r.t xy-plane, i (degrees)
- OM     Longitude of Ascending Node, OMEGA, (degrees)
- W      Argument of Perifocus, w (degrees)
- Tp     Time of periapsis (Julian day number)
- N      Mean motion, n (degrees/day)
- MA     Mean anomaly, M (degrees)
- TA     True anomaly, nu (degrees)
- A      Semi-major axis, a (AU)
- AD     Apoapsis distance (AU)
- PR     Sidereal orbit period (day)